# URL Designs with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url, uri

I am new to Java with knowledge MVC architecture and JSP.

I have created a website with multiple JSP pages (on MVC architecture) which is data dependent and data is displayed as the request parameters passed in the URL.

My URL is something like this:

```
localhost:8080/web/Area.jsp?name=stack&place=internet
```

What i want to achieve for better SEO is something like this

```
localhost:8080/web/stack/internet
```

I have tried `URlRewritefilter` but the XML file being created is too big and is causing Java out of memory errors.

I aim to achieve this through java code/framework (please suggest which I should learn) where in the requested data can be processed by the jsp in backend and achieve a cleaner URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not a Java tech but a server URL rewrite tech. If you are using Apache just try the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a JEE filter which does a kind of pre-controller work, translating that SEO-friendly format you write about to the format your app needs (for example, if you had a struts 1 application with a url like

somemachine:xxxx/web/myAction.do?name=stack&place=internet

it should be trivial to write a filter which translated something like

somemachine:xxxx/web/myAction/stack/internet

into the real URL and managed it internally to the server

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html